# Collecting Unique Items from large data set over multiple text files

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to collect lists of names from multiple text files. May of the names in these files are similar / repeating. I am trying to ensure that PowerShell returns a single text file with all of the unique items. In looking at the data it looks like the script is gathering 271/296 of the unique items. I'm guessing that some of the data is being flagged as duplicates when it shouldn't, any suggestions?

```
#Take content of each file (all names) and add unique values to text file  
#for each unique value, create a row & check to see which txt files contain 

function List {
        $nofiles = Read-Host "How many files are we pulling from?"
        $data = @()
        for ($i = 0;$i -lt $nofiles; $i++)
        {
            $data += Read-Host "Give me the file name for file # $($i+1)"
        }


        return $data
}


function Aggregate ($array) {

        Get-Content $array | Sort-Object -unique | Out-File newaggregate.txt 
}





#SCRIPT BODY
$data = List
aggregate ($data)
```

I was expecting this code to catch everything, but it's missing some items that look very similar. List of missing names and their similar match:

```
CORPINZUTL16  MISSING FROM OUTFILE
CORPINZTRACE  MISSING FROM OUTFILE
CORPINZADMIN  Found In File
```

I have about 20 examples like this one. Apparently the Get-Content -Unique is not checking every character in a line. Can anyone recommend a better way of checking each line or possibly forcing the get-character to check full names?

Comment: Without seeing part of your source data it's difficult to help. Your `Sort-Object -Unique` sorts only per input file and overwrites `aggregate.txt` with each input file. As Get-Content accepts arrays as input don't iterate $array with a for but feed directly to gc..

Comment: The source data is 8 text files. Each text file has a list of computer names that follow the same naming convention. I'm attempting to aggregate the lists and pull unique values. I need to know which machines are missing from each list (none of the lists are considered complete)

Comment: I do understand that, but you'll have to put all the files together and then sort unique, ATM you sort each file individually and overwrite the output file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, once I fixed that I was able to run the code as intended. The next step is for me to check each source file and list which names from the aggregate array are not present in each file. Do you have any suggestions as to how to go about this? I'm new to Powershell, and it looks like sending the info to an excel file would be painful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for demonstration this line creates 3 txt files with numbers

```
for($i=1;$i -lt 4;$i++){set-content -path "$i.txt" -value ($i..$($i+7))}
```

---

```
1.txt | 2.txt | 3.txt | newaggregate.txt
1     |       |       | 1
2     | 2     |       | 2
3     | 3     | 3     | 3 
4     | 4     | 4     | 4
5     | 5     | 5     | 5
6     | 6     | 6     | 6
7     | 7     | 7     | 7
8     | 8     | 8     | 8
      | 9     | 9     | 9
      |       | 10    | 10
```

Here using `Get-Content` with a range `[1-3]` of files

```
Get-Content [1-3].txt | Sort-Object {[int]$_}  -Unique | Out-File newaggregate.txt

$All = Get-Content .\newaggregate.txt
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem [1-3].txt)){
    Compare-Object $All (Get-Content $file.FullName) | 
        Select-Object @{n='File';e={$File}},
                      @{n="Missing";e={$_.InputObject}} -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
}
```

---

```
File                     Missing
----                     -------
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\1.txt 9
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\1.txt 10
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\2.txt 1
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\2.txt 10
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\3.txt 1
Q:\Test\2019\05\07\3.txt 2
```

Comment: Building on my example to show how to compare the single files with `Compare-Object` against the `newaggregate.txt`

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to achieve this one is using `select-object -Unique` which works when data is not sorted and can be used for small data or lists.

When dealing with large files we can use `get-Unique` command which works with sorted input, if input data is not sorted then it will give wrong results.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Get-Content | measure -Line #225949

Get-ChildItem *.txt | Get-Content | sort | Get-Unique | measure -Line #119650
```

Here is my command for multiple files :

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Get-Content | sort | Get-Unique >> Unique.txt
```